# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toHexString') in ether.js

Tags: javascript, blockchain

Please don't judge, i've no idea what to do and how to do :)

**My code:**
ether.js ( ^5.6.0)

```
import { ThirdwebSDK } from '@3rdweb/sdk'
import { ethers } from 'ethers'

const sdk = new ThirdwebSDK(
  new ethers.Wallet(
    process.env.METAMASK_PRIVATE_KEY,
    ethers.getDefaultProvider(
      'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/'
    )
  ) 
)
```

**bug**
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using JavaScript and getting this error then You made a mistake while importing dotenv. you are using **".config"** as property . Use it like a method like following

**require("dotenv").config()**

It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Another problem you might have is where your .env is located. Make sure that your .env is in the same folder as your code.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I actually missed saving an updated .env file.  When I saved the updated .env properly this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely messed up env variable. Check if `METAMASK_PRIVATE_KEY` is the correct name. Because otherwise it will throw `undefined` and one of the ethersjs library will try to run `hexToString()` method on `undefined` value, thus you get the error.

EDIT:

You might as well forget to include this in your code:

```js
import {} from 'dotenv/config' 

// or if its not ESmodule 

require('dotenv').config()
```

Absence of this import will throw `undefined` as well when you access env variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem aswell. I used a constructor for my sol contract that looked as following:

```
constructor(
        address vrfCoordinatorV2,
        uint256 entranceFee,
        bytes32 gasLane,
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        uint32 callbackGasLimit,
        uint256 interval
    )
```

After alot of frustration i found out that my arguments for the deploy script wasn't lined up in the same order. This was causing the error:

```
"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toHexString')"
```

In my case the arguments needed to be lined up as following:

```
const args = [
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
        networkConfig[chainId]["raffleEntranceFee"],
        networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"],
        subscriptionId,
        networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"],
        networkConfig[chainId]["keepersUpdateInterval"],
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is that you've edited the .env file and forgotten to save it. Hence the script won't see the new entry.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).